# What are the advantages of docker containers over statically linked EXEs?

Tags: docker

I am struggling to understand exactly what practical problem docker solves. Docker prescribes "one process per container". If your container only encapsulates one program/process, then what advantage is there over a statically linked executable? Doesn't this do basically the same thing (encapsulate a program) in a much more simple and efficient way?

Comment: Great question. It's indeed best to think of a docker container as a process but it's really also small vm with its own environment, networking, logging, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker resolve a list of common problems that a statically linked exe does not:

- You distribute your app with folders in a known file system, environment variables initialized, and network settings previously created and established to work. Not in risky setup time with your app running for first time trying to create folders, paths, environment vars, etc. and getting crashed for permissions errors, network unidentified, ABI incompatibilities, etc.
- It is more convenient to setup microservices architectures. Many instances running each one in its own environment without conflicting races and offering tools for distribute, load and running your backend services.

Comment: 1) presumably the secrets aren't baked into the docker image so you still need to pass this in somehow anyway. 2) the tooling is a strong point in favor of docker.

Comment: ABI compatibilities are not "secret" values. If your binaries were created in a Ubuntu machine, and you are distributing those binaries only, even statically linked, any other OS like Red Hat, CoreOS, etc. are not guarantee for running it, Probably you should distribute the source code or make different binaries for every target OS, and distribution  packages for apt-get, yum, etc. Or you only creates and distribute a docker image to target machines ready for load and running Docker images.

Comment: oh right, yeah the ABI compatibility thing is a reasonable point in principle, maybe not heaps important for my use case, essentially i see that as choosing one OS, let's call it "DockerOS".

Answer (score 1):

Well no.

It's more like `chroot()` or `jail()` or `pledge()` the benefit of docker is that you can easily change user context in which the program is running.

Another benefit is that you can use a complete different OS then the host is. e. g.: MS Dotnet core 1 on Linux.

Comment: hm so docker is another way to run windows apps on linux. when might you want to "change user context" and how is that easier with docker than with an exe file?

Comment: To run win <> linux was just a example. Let ask me another question how easy is it to run an exe/bin file with limited privileges or x instances of the same exe/bin file independently ?

Comment: for 2), just `for i in $(seq x); do ./app & done`. for 1) I'm not that familiar with running with limited privileges etc but I imagine you could have a program `limit` and you go `limit app` and it does that somehow. the 1) use case is not so relevant to me.